# Is this a MySQL bug?

Tags: mysql, semi-join

I was running this query against [sakila database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) on MySQL `8.0.17`:

```
select * from film _1 where (
    exists (
        select * from film_actor where (
            select * from (
                select film_id=_1.film_id and actor_id=1
            ) _2
        )
    )
);
```

This gives `0` results. But if I run this:

```
select * from film _1 where (
    exists (
        select * from film_actor where (
            select film_id=_1.film_id and actor_id=1
        )
    )
);
```

I got `19` results, which is expected.

Basically I wrapped the `where` condition with `select * from` and suddenly got the wrong result.

To my understanding, wrapping any table value with `select * from` should give identical result.

I've created [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bfd092299983f558ecffda049803de3).

Comment: Neither of those code snippets looks right.

Comment: `select film_id=_1.film_id and actor_id=1` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: @SalmanA select all films of actor 1.

Comment: Using subselects like this really confusing. Try and express this as a series of `JOIN` operations instead.

Comment: See about joins

Comment: Sorry guys this may be confusing, but it's generated, not manually written. So I just want to know why the result is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is confirmed to be a bug in MySQL. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97461.